# Questions on applying a private Stylesheet to another Notebook

Tags: stylesheet

I have a notebook, let's call it *Ideal.nb* for short, with some styles defined in it and some were altered from what it inherits from *Default.nb*.

If I want to reuse this stylesheet in my notebook *ImportingSS.nb*, what has to be done to achieve it?

I tried:

1. Throw out all cells from the Notebook *Ideal.nb* itself and store this empty notebook as *IdealSS.nb*. 
   In my notebook *ImportingSS.nb*, go through **Format>Stylesheets>Other** and select *IdealSS.nb* there. However, if I want to assign one of the styles to a cell through **Format>Style** I have no choice but **other**! 
   However, in the shown box I can manually enter **Input** and I get Courier 10 pt bold, what was defined in Ideal.nb's private stylesheet (and also in *Default.nb*). I also tried to assign **Output**, which is Courier 10 pt regular face and this also applies. Then I made another cell and pasted the Lorem Ipsum blind text inro it and made this cell a Text cell: It also turned to Arial Font, but the size was 14 pt rather than 10 pt as in *Ideal.nb*'s private stylesheet! It looks like it took this definition from *Default.nb*, since there Text is Arial 14 pt. - It looks, this way does not work as expected!
2. Take *IdealSS.nb* created in step 1 (which is empty, but still has the associated private stylesheet in it) and copy/paste all cells from *ImportingSS.nb* to it. Then store it as *ImportingSS.nb*. I also tried to paste some Lorem ipsum blind text, put a tab after the first word of each paragraph in it and applied my style Text-80 to it (negative indentation with 80 units) and that worked such that the first word was outdented: The Selection from **Format>Style** worked as usual (not only "other"). I had to select my additional style through **other** but the drop-down selection box there did not let me select from my privately defined styles. I had to completely enter the wanted name. Selecting privately defined new styles by fully entering their names was also necessary in Ideal.nb (it would be nice, if the selection offers all defined styles by the drop-down selection, does anyone know, how to achieve this?

**1. What is the recommended way to apply a foreign stylesheet to an existing notebook?**

**2. What is the recommended way to export a private stylesheet?**